# How to export painted image using html5 canvas tag?

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

Good afternoon,

I am trying to extend websanova wPaint plugin using Kinetic.js jQuery library.

Here is what I have done: http://jandeccpl.info/woodensigns/wPaint-master/

I want to export all data in canvas as a png or jpeg, But as I click on save image it only save background image not the two images whose location is set by user by dragging on canvas.

Kindly tell me how I can I export the entire canvas data as png/jpeg image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to base64.